# what is the effect of adding another stack to a PDA

Tags: automata

does it increase the power of a push down automata? or does it have no effect on the power of the PDA ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having two (or more) stacks in a PDA is equivalent to having a Turing machine. See Problem 1.b [here](http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/class/fa08/cs373/Problem_Sets/hw9-sol.pdf).